# How to convert ffmpeg complex_filter to ffmpeg-python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, scripting, video-editing, ffmpeg-python

I am trying to learn to convert ffmpeg command line background blur filter to `ffmpeg-python` format.
`'-lavfi'` and `[0:v]scale=ih*16/9:-1,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[bg][0:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,crop=h=iw*9/16`

Basic examples from https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python are good to learn simple tricks, but How to learn to the full transformation syntax?

Comment: First off, I don't know anything about ffmpeg. But after briefly reading the API docs, it seems that a lot of the filter functions you want to use are not implemented (i.e. boxblur). You can implement them yourself using the `ffmpeg.filter()` function to apply a custom filter. [Check it out](https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/#ffmpeg.filter). Hope this helps!

Comment: If you could post a sample command line argument, maybe I could help

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if you figured this or not ... but here's an approach that worked for me.

**Tip1:** A pre-requisite for using the library to 'encode any filter' is
understanding the ffmpeg command line syntax.

**Tip2:** In general, `ffmpeg.filter()` takes the filter name as first param. This is followed by all the filter conditions. This function returns the stream downstream to the filter node you just created.

For example: In the example ffmpeg command line from the question... reading it tells me that you want to scale the video and then apply the boxblur filter followed by crop.

So you'd represent this in `ffmpeg-python` terms as

```py
# create a stream object, Note that any supplied kwargs are passed to ffmpeg verbatim
my_vid_stream = ffmpeg.input(input_file, "lavfi")

# The input() returns a stream object has what is called 'base_object' which represents the outgoing edge of an upstream 
# node and can be used to create more downstream nodes. That is what we will do. This stream base_object has two properties, 
# audio and video .. assign the video stream to a new variable, we will be creating filters to only video stream, 
# as indicated by [0:v] in ffmpeg command line.
my_vid_stream = mystream.video

# ffmpeg.filter() takes the upstream node followed by the name of the filter, followed by the configuration of the filter
# first filter you wanted to apply is 'scale' filter. So...
my_vid_stream = ffmpeg.filter(my_vid_stream,"scale","ih*16/9:-1")

# next to the upstream node create a new filter which does the boxblur operation per your specs. so .. 
my_vid_stream = ffmpeg.filter(my_vid_stream,"boxblur", "min(h\,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[bg][0:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2")

# finally apply the crop filter to it's upstream node and assign the output stream back to the same variable. so ... 
my_vid_stream = ffmpeg.filter(my_vid_stream, "crop", h="iw*9/16")

# now generate the output node and write it to an output file.
my_vid_stream = ffmpeg.output(my_vid_stream,output_file)
## to see your pipeline in action. call the ffmpeg.run(my_vid_stream)
```

Hope this helps you or anyone else struggling to effectively utilize this lib.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on `FFmpeg-python` there is much flexibility in adding custom commands. Here I am mentioning an example where I am adding a loop to overlay videos and adding a concatenate filter you can learn from here how to add reset filters.

```
        audios = []
        inputs = []
        #generate an empty audio
        e_aud_src = rendering_helper.generate_empty_audio(0.1)
        e_aud = (
            ffmpeg.input(e_aud_src)
                .audio
        )

        for k, i in enumerate(videos):
            inp = ffmpeg.input(i['src'], ss=i['start'],  t=(i['end'] - i['start']))

            inp_f = (inp.filter_multi_output('split')[k]
                        .filter_('scale', width=(i['width'] * Factors().factors['w_factor']), height=(i['height'] * Factors().factors['h_factor'])).filter('setsar', '1/1')
                        .setpts(f"PTS-STARTPTS+{i['showtime']}/TB"))

            audio = ffmpeg.probe(i['src'], select_streams='a')
            if audio['streams'] and i['muted'] == False:
                a = (inp.audio.filter('adelay', f"{i['showtime'] * 1000}|{i['showtime'] * 1000}"))
            else: 
                a = e_aud
            audios.append(a) 

            e_frame = (e_frame.overlay(inp_f, x=(i['xpos'] * Factors().factors['w_factor']), y=(i['ypos'] * Factors().factors['h_factor']), eof_action='pass'))

        
        mix_audios = ffmpeg.filter_(audios, 'amix') if len(audios) > 1 else audios[0]
        inp_con = ffmpeg.concat(e_frame, mix_audios, v=1, a=1)
        return inp_con
```

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:
Here we have 3 videos that are faded black into eachother.
I found that a filter having more than one input will accept a tuple as first parameter, maybe also a list.

And the y="-y" thing was also just tried - it seems this library is intuitive enough, alt least given my twisted (not that twisted) mind.

```
import ffmpeg
infile = "test-video.mp4"
outfile = str(infile) +'.crossfade.mp4'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    faded = ffmpeg.input(infile, ss=10, to=21)
    into = ffmpeg.input(infile, ss=30, to=41)
    faded = ffmpeg.filter((faded, into), 'xfade', transition="fadeblack", duration=1, offset=10)
    into = ffmpeg.input(infile, ss=60, to=71)
    faded = ffmpeg.filter((faded, into), 'xfade', transition="fadeblack", duration=1, offset=20)
    # overwrite: n="-n" means never , same for y="-y" always
    written = ffmpeg.output(faded, outfile, y="-y")
    ffmpeg.run(written)
```

Comment: I think `n=None` or `y=None` will also work. seems to be a bug that `y=""` does not work